# How to get RelayJS to understand that a response from GraphQL is an array of items, not just a single item

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have a GraphQL server running with a schema roughly like this:

```
type Card {
  id: String!
  name: String
}

type Query {
  card(name: String!): Card
  cards(power: String): [Card]
}
```

Notice that I have a query on a single card, but also on multiple cards. When I use the GraphIQl UI and make a query like this "query {cards { name }}" I get back an array of cards, as expected.

However, I have a RelayContainer that is making the same query, but the props that come back are just the first result, rather than an array of results.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Hello world!</h1>
        <CardList cards={this.props.cards} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(MyApp, {
  fragments: {
    card: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Card {
        name
      }
    `,
    cards: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Card {
        ${CardList.getFragment('cards')}
      }
    `
  },
});
```

and the CardList component is set up with the Container like this:

```js
class CardList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.cards}</div> // UNEXPECTED - this.props.cards is the first card, not an array for me to .map over
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(CardList, {
  fragments: {
    cards: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Card {
        name
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Anybody have any suggestions? This is day 2 of me diving into GraphQL and Relay, so I might be making a very basic mistake for all I know.

Comment: Take a look at how the TODO Relay example works. Your GraphQL schema isn't correct for Relay as you need to use `connectionsDefinition` from https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/a04a51486c2576c4a0dcdb091023e1bda0d0a5fe/examples/todo/data/schema.js#L93-L100

Answer (score 12):

You probably want a `@relay(plural: true)` directive on your `cards` query fragment. There is an example of a plural field in action [in the Star Wars example](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/2d822400dbcf14f9636ab3149477f4ff0a0ee466/examples/star-wars/js/components/StarWarsApp.js#L26) in the Relay repo.

If you care about pagination, though, you probably want a connection instead of a plural field. Connections are described [in the Relay docs](http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html#content) and implemented in [graphql-relay-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#connections).

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting down this path to explore. One thing I'm still not fully grokking though is that the examples all show a connection starting with  a singular object at the base. eg. Faction has many Ships, Todo has many Todo items, etc. However, what if you want a plural thing at the root? (eg AllShips)

Comment: Right now, you can't have a connection at the root. This is a known limitation, but we plan to resolve it and progress is [being tracked here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/112). For now, the workaround is to wrap such things in another root field (like, `viewer`, for example).

Comment: So a connection is the appropriate way to enabled Relay-specific pagination? Even if it does not relate to entity relationships, but instead just a query on accounts, where there may be millions of accounts?