# Cannot get Relay to make GraphQL Call over the network

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I am new to Relay, and I am having problems making it work with a GraphQL server.

I have adapted the [Tea](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) sample from the relay homepage to the SWAPI relay service. I cloned [swapi-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql), and added cors to the express server. I tested the link with this code:

```
var query = `
  {
    allFilms {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

fetch("http://localhost:50515/graphiql?query=" + query)
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(json=>console.log(json))
```

I got a response from the server, I saw some network action, it worked! I can communicate with the graphiql service.

Next, I created a query that was structured similar to the TeaStoreQuery. I [tested](https://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/?query=query%20AllFilmQuery%20%7B%0A%20%20allFilms%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...filmListFragment%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20filmListFragment%20on%20FilmsConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...filmFragment%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20filmFragment%20on%20Film%20%7B%0A%20%20id%0A%20%20title%0A%20%20releaseDate%0A%7D&operationName=AllFilmQuery) it, and it returned the expected results.

```
query AllFilmQuery {
  allFilms {
    ...filmListFragment
  }
}

fragment filmListFragment on FilmsConnection {
  edges {
    node {
      ...filmFragment
    }
  }
}

fragment filmFragment on Film {
  id
  title
  releaseDate
}
```

**HOW DO YOU MAKE THIS WORK WITH RELAY??**

I cannot figure out how to use Relay to query the server. Here is the code that I adapted from the Tea sample.

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { 
  RootContainer, 
  createContainer, 
  Route, 
  injectNetworkLayer 
} from 'react-relay'

// React component for each star wars film
const Film = ({ id, title, releaseDate }) => 
  <li key={id}>
    {title} (<em>{releaseDate}</em>)
  </li>

// Relay container for each film
const FilmContainer = createContainer(Film, {
  fragments: {
    film: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Film {
        id,
        title,
        releaseDate
      }
    `
  }
})               

// React component for listing films       
const FilmList = ({ films=[] }) => 
  <ul>
    {films.map(
      film => <Film {...film} />
    )}
  </ul>

// Relay container for Listing all Films
const FilmListContainer = createContainer(FilmList, {
  fragments: {
    films: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on FilmsConnection {
        edges {
          node {
            ${ Film.getFragment('film') }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
})    

// The Home Route
class FilmHomeRoute extends Route {
  static routeName = 'Home'
  static queries = {
    allFilms: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query AllFilmQuery {
        allFilms {
          ${Component.getFragment('allFilms')}
        }
      }
    `
  }
}

// Is this how you setup a network layer
// I am using CORS, and I testing the graphql service with fetch
// The graphql service works but Relay never seems to try to connect
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:50515/graphiql')
)

render(
  <RootContainer
    Component={FilmListContainer}
    route={new FilmHomeRoute()}
  />,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

When I run this sample ([source](http://output.jsbin.com/kayofi/edit) | [output](http://output.jsbin.com/kayofi/quiet)) I do not see any attempts at making network requests. I do see an error "Cannot render map of null". It seems like it cannot map the allfilms data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to section 5.1 of [this document](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm#sec-Fields), the "Relay Object Identification Specification":

> Relay‐compliant servers may expose root fields that are not plural identifying root fields; the Relay client will just be unable to use those fields as root fields in its queries.

Based on this specification, Relay can not query plural fields at the root of a query unless the field takes a list of arguments that exactly maps to the results. That means the `allFilms` field cannot be used with Relay. You can read more about the limitations in this other StackOverflow answer: [How to get RelayJS to understand that a response from GraphQL is an array of items, not just a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491117/how-to-get-relayjs-to-understand-that-a-response-from-graphql-is-an-array-of-ite)

If you would like to have a GraphQL schema with root fields that return arrays, you might want to use a different GraphQL client, since Relay is particularly restrictive in what kinds of schemas it works with. graphql.org has a list: http://graphql.org/code/#graphql-clients

Comment: Does this mean that this example with the SWAPI is impossible? or do I need to use something like: @relay(plural: true) ?

Comment: I think `plural: true` is not possible on the root field of a query, so I think it's actually impossible to query for `allFilms` on that schema with Relay. I think this is one of the reasons Relay-compatible schemas often have the root query be `{ viewer }`, to get around this limitation.

Comment: What is the simplest way to connect to GraphAPI with Relay? Is there a way to do it with a single component, a single route, and just console.log that relay has made a request and you have a response? I don't see anything at all in the network panel.

Comment: I'm the lead on Apollo Client, an alternative to Relay that is very simple to set up with just one component. you could give that a try: http://dev.apollodata.com/

Comment: Yea, I saw that. I was putting together a presentation on GraphQL/Relay. I reviewed Apollo Client and included some information about ya'll in my pres.  Thanks!